# React Native - NavigatorIOS - Disable pop gesture

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to disable the swipe back gesture in NavigatorIOS which pops the current scene.

I have seen methods using Navigator.SceneConfigs but none of this applies to NavigatorIOS.

My current code as it stands is as follows.

```
<NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute={{
        title: 'Favourites',
        component: Favourites,
        passProps: {
            content: this.state.content,
            user: this.state.userLoggedIn,
            favsPage: false,
            setFavourites: this.setFavourites,
            alterContent: this.alterContent,
            retrieve: this.retrieve,
            retrieveContent: this.retrieveContent,
            events: this.eventEmitter
        }
    }}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the various replace methods. They may get you the desired affect.

> `replace(route)` - Replace the route for the current page and immediately load the view for the new
>
> `routereplacePrevious(route)` - Replace the route/view for the previous page
>
> `replacePreviousAndPop(route)`- Replaces the previous route/view and transitions back to it